# What is the name of this game? And what type is it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to research more about this game's strategies, but I don't know what is its name is in English.

The game is like this (the gadget is just named Picture Puzzle):

[image: Sliding block puzzle before and after solution]

The objective is to slide the blank cell to the lower-right cell.

What exactly is its name? And is it considered a board-game?

Comment: Looks like the objective is to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @Callithumpian Yeah, I forgot to mention it. I think it is pretty popular thought. Bad thing is, in my language, there is no word to describe that game, we just call them like "Picture Puzzle" :( I need a exactly name, so that I can use Google to research more about it.

Comment: This belongs on [gaming.se].

Comment: @zzzzBov: just because there are videogame implementation of this game, it does not really classify it as a videogame. I think it is on topic here, as it is a request for an English word. I think noone would vote to close if the question was, for instance, "what is the name of that game where you jump over a rope?".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are *[sliding puzzles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle)*.

Answer (score 10):

The "15 puzzle" since in the 1880s popular version the tiles were numbered 1 to 15 ... [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In French we call it [Jeu de Taquin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taquin).

This name is *internationally* (so in English) [used by mathematician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_taquin) to describe problems similar to the one your game raise.

Answer (score 0):

Other people that sell these call them sliding tile puzzles.